# NSDate's initWithString: is returning nil

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, protocols, nsdate, categories

I'm using [Stig Brautaset](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework)'s JSON framework serialize some objects, including NSDates (which are not directly supported).

I decided to use NSDate's description as the JSONFragment representation of a date (I don't care about the minor loss of precision incurred in doing so).

To extend [Stig Brautaset](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework)'s JSON framework to include NSDates, I defined a category:

```
@interface NSDate  (NSDate_JSON) <JSONInitializer>

-(NSString *) JSONFragment;

@end
```

To recreate an NSDate (and other classes) from JSON, I defined a protocol with the following initializer:

```
@protocol JSONInitializer <NSObject>

-(id) initWithJSONRepresentation: (NSString *) aJSONRepresentation;

@end
```

I'm having issues with this initializer. In NSDate's case, it just calls initWithString:, and that's were I get into trouble: it always returns nil. This is the implementation:

```
#import "NSDate+JSON.h"


@implementation NSDate (NSDate_JSON)

-(NSString *) JSONFragment{
    NSString *strRepr = [self description];
    return [strRepr JSONFragment];
}

-(id) initWithJSONRepresentation:(NSString *)aJSONRepresentation{


    return [self initWithString: aJSONRepresentation]; //returns nil!
}
@end
```

I'm not sure what's going on. Besides, the compiler warns me that the initWithString: method in initWithJSONRepresentation: could not be found.

Anybody knows what might be going on?

The full source code for a test case is available [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3978473/forums/testCase.zip).

Comment: What does `aJSONRepresentation` look like?

Comment: It's exactly the same as NSDate's description

Comment: @Bavarious OK, you're right, AJSONRepresentation is description inside double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test program is:

```
NSDate *d1 = [[[NSDate alloc] init] autorelease];
NSString *repr = [d1 JSONFragment];

NSDate *dd = [[[NSDate alloc] initWithString:[d1 description]] autorelease ];
NSDate *d2 = [[[NSDate alloc] initWithJSONRepresentation:repr] autorelease];
```

Your `-JSONFragment` category method is:

```
-(NSString *) JSONFragment{
    NSString *strRepr = [self description];
    return [strRepr JSONFragment];
}
```

What’s happening in this method is that you obtain a string representation of that date using `-description`, and then a JSON representation of that string using `-JSONFragment`.

In SBJSON, `-JSONFragment` returns the representation of a given object as JSON data. The JSON specification requires that strings are quoted. In your program:

```
NSString *repr = [d1 JSONFragment];
```

`repr` contains a string like `@"\"2011-04-29 10:20:30 -0600\""`. Because of the quotes, that string is not a valid string to be used with `-[NSDate initWithString:]`.

If you change:

```
NSString *repr = [d1 JSONFragment];
```

to:

```
NSString *repr = [[d1 JSONFragment] JSONFragmentValue];
```

so that SBJSON parses that fragment and returns a string without the quotes, it should work.

Comment: +1: Dave's still probably right about relying on `description`'s output, though.

Comment: @Josh I’m not sure about that. The documentation for `-[NSDate description]` and `-[NSDate initWithString:]` is very specific about the string representation.

Comment: True, and I'll bow to your superior experience on this, but if I had to guess, given there's no documentation saying "`description` is valid input for `initWithString`", I'd say Apple'd be more willing to change the behavior of a method for logging than a method for creating objects. Or, I don't know, is `description` supposed to be used for other things?

Comment: @Josh Ha, I know nothing about this superior experience you’re talking about — and it isn’t true. :-P What caught my eye is that, as you’ve said, -description is normally used for logging. However, they have documented a very specific format for the return value. They’re certainly aware that changing that method to return a different format would potentially break applications, so my guess is that they wouldn’t do it. Instead, they’d provide another method.

Comment: I'll change my code to use timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate, hopefully it should be more reliable and work both in OSX and iOS.

Comment: Well, you seem to be a professional, and I am simply an enthusiast who's good at figuring things out... Anyways, another point for your side that I just thought of is that `description` is supposed to be something like a complete, um, description of the object, and a natural form for that is "the international string representation".

Comment: Interesting: I just noticed that Apple no longer explicitly guarantees the format [of the `description` string](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188--description), whereas [`initWithString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188--initWithString_) still has the same strict format. Still inconclusive, but potentially a gotcha! from Lion.

Comment: @Josh Interesting indeed; I wasn’t expecting that. I suspect Dave filed a documentation radar! :D

Answer (score 3):

You should *always* use an `NSDateFormatter` when attempting to convert a string into a date or vice versa.  `-initWithString:` does exist on the Mac, but not on iOS.  It requires the string to be in an extremely precise format.  Using a date formatter is by far the superior solution.

And as a side note, your code would break if Apple ever decided to change the format of `-[NSDate description]`.

Comment: If the method doesn't exist on iOS, and I was using iOS, shouldn't the application crash?

Comment: It's probably there, just not as API, and you shouldn't rely on undocumented methods. `NSDateFormatter` is still the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason `initWithString:` can't be found is that unless you're importing Foundation and didn't show us here, your code can't see NSDate.h, so it doesn't know that `initWithString:` exists.

Dave's quite right about relying on `description` and using an `NSDateFormatter` instead. It doesn't seem likely that `description` will change, but there's no guarantee that it will continue to be valid input for `initWithString:` which [has a strict input requirement](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188--initWithString_):

> A string that specifies a date and time value in the international string representation format — `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS ±HHMM`, where `±HHMM` is a time zone offset in hours and minutes from GMT (for example, “`2001-03-24 10:45:32 +0600`”).
>
> You must specify all fields of the format string, including the time zone offset, which must have a plus or minus sign prefix.

If your string differs in any way (including, as has become apparent, having quotes in it), you'll get `nil`.