# How to convert an NSData into an NSString Hex string?

Tags: macos, cocoa

When I call `-description` on an `NSData` object, I see a pretty Hex string of the `NSData` object's bytes like:

```
<f6e7cd28 0fc5b5d4 88f8394b af216506 bc1bba86 4d5b483d>
```

I'd like to get this representation of the data (minus the lt/gt quotes) into an in-memory `NSString` so I can work with it..  I'd prefer not to call `-[NSData description]` and then just trim the lt/gt quotes (because I assume that is not a guaranteed aspect of `NSData`'s public interface and is subject change in the future).

What's the simplest way to get this representation of an `NSData` object into an `NSString` object (other than calling `-description`)?

Comment: So, why not description? (Really curious. Suspect I'll learn something.)

Comment: @Steven: `description`'s output may change across system versions. For example, `-[NSDate description]` was, pre-Lion, documented as returning a string with exactly the same format as was required for `-[NSDate initWithString:]`; that guarantee is no longer made. Brief discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837777/nsdates-initwithstring-is-returning-nil/5837852

Comment: `description` should be used for debugging purposes only, because you have no guaranty that the value returned by the `description` method won't change in future releases (even if it is unlikely). For example nothing tells your that Apple won't decide some day that if `[NSData length]>200`, then the string returned by `description` will be clipped in the middle... or anything similar. So this is why its may not be a good practice to rely on what is returned by `description` for anything else than debugging/logging.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. I have to admit, I've provided custom descriptions for my own debugging purposes.

Comment: I wrote an NSData to hexadecimal NSString category you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9084784/153040 It's similar to **AliSoftware**'s answer.

Comment: When debugging: Fast way to inspect/view the hex as a readable string (when applicable): http://stackoverflow.com/a/38225931/1054573

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to serialize an NSData into a hexadeximal string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305225/best-way-to-serialize-an-nsdata-into-a-hexadeximal-string)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Keep in mind that any `String(format: ...)` solution will be terribly slow (for large data)

```
NSData *data = ...;
NSUInteger capacity = data.length * 2;
NSMutableString *sbuf = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:capacity];
const unsigned char *buf = data.bytes;
NSInteger i;
for (i=0; i<data.length; ++i) {
  [sbuf appendFormat:@"%02X", (NSUInteger)buf[i]];
}
```

If you need something **more performant** try this:

```
static inline char itoh(int i) {
    if (i > 9) return 'A' + (i - 10);
    return '0' + i;
}

NSString * NSDataToHex(NSData *data) {
    NSUInteger i, len;
    unsigned char *buf, *bytes;
    
    len = data.length;
    bytes = (unsigned char*)data.bytes;
    buf = malloc(len*2);
    
    for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
        buf[i*2] = itoh((bytes[i] >> 4) & 0xF);
        buf[i*2+1] = itoh(bytes[i] & 0xF);
    }
    
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:buf
                                          length:len*2
                                        encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                    freeWhenDone:YES];
}
```

Swift version

```
private extension Data {
    var hexadecimalString: String {
        let charA: UInt8 = 0x61
        let char0: UInt8 = 0x30
        func byteToChar(_ b: UInt8) -> Character {
            Character(UnicodeScalar(b > 9 ? charA + b - 10 : char0 + b))
        }
        let hexChars = flatMap {[
            byteToChar(($0 >> 4) & 0xF),
            byteToChar($0 & 0xF)
        ]}
        return String(hexChars)
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe `var p = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.alloc(length * 2)` can be `let p = ...` (via Swift 2 compiler warning)

Comment: This was worth coming here just to learn about `String(bytesNoCopy:length:encoding:)`. The performance on this is great...learned a few things from it.

Comment: If you are an developer that uses Realm, you can use this to get the encryption key from the Keychain.

Answer (score 30):

I agree on the solution *not* to call `description` which is to be reserved for debugging, so good point and good question :)

The easiest solution is to loop thru the bytes of the `NSData` and construct the NSString from it. Use `[yourData bytes]` to access the bytes, and build the string into an `NSMutableString`.

Here is an example by implementing this using a category of NSData

```
@interface NSData(Hex)
-(NSString*)hexRepresentationWithSpaces_AS:(BOOL)spaces;
@end

@implementation NSData(Hex)
-(NSString*)hexRepresentationWithSpaces_AS:(BOOL)spaces
{
    const unsigned char* bytes = (const unsigned char*)[self bytes];
    NSUInteger nbBytes = [self length];
    //If spaces is true, insert a space every this many input bytes (twice this many output characters).
    static const NSUInteger spaceEveryThisManyBytes = 4UL;
    //If spaces is true, insert a line-break instead of a space every this many spaces.
    static const NSUInteger lineBreakEveryThisManySpaces = 4UL;
    const NSUInteger lineBreakEveryThisManyBytes = spaceEveryThisManyBytes * lineBreakEveryThisManySpaces;
    NSUInteger strLen = 2*nbBytes + (spaces ? nbBytes/spaceEveryThisManyBytes : 0);

    NSMutableString* hex = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:strLen];
    for(NSUInteger i=0; i<nbBytes; ) {
        [hex appendFormat:@"%02X", bytes[i]];
        //We need to increment here so that the every-n-bytes computations are right.
        ++i;

        if (spaces) {
            if (i % lineBreakEveryThisManyBytes == 0) [hex appendString:@"\n"];
            else if (i % spaceEveryThisManyBytes == 0) [hex appendString:@" "];
        }
    }
    return [hex autorelease];
}
@end
```

Usage:

```
NSData* data = ...
NSString* hex = [data hexRepresentationWithSpaces_AS:YES];
```

Comment: Nitpick: If you want to match description you'd want "%02x", rather than "%02X". (The difference is lowercase vs. uppercase.)

Comment: Nice snippet. I've made it available as gist with minor modifications here: https://gist.github.com/1443455

Comment: When I use this solution hex value 90 comes out as ffffff90. What's up with that?

Comment: your 0x90 input value is a signed integer maybe, instead of unsigned? Explaining the sign bit propagation, and the representation you got, which looks like 2's-complement hex form? What is your exact code?

Answer (score 26):

Just wanted to add that @PassKits's method can be written very elegantly using Swift 3 since `Data` now is a collection.

```
extension Data { 
    var hex: String {
        var hexString = ""
        for byte in self {
            hexString += String(format: "%02X", byte)
        }

        return hexString
    }
}
```

Or ...

```
extension Data {
    var hex: String {
        return self.map { b in String(format: "%02X", b) }.joined()
    }
}
```

Or even ...

```
extension Data {
    var hex: String {
        return self.reduce("") { string, byte in
            string + String(format: "%02X", byte)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a computed property might fit the Swift style a bit better as well

Answer (score 22):

I liked @Erik_Aigner's answer the best. I just refactored it a bit:

```
NSData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:"acani" length:5];
NSUInteger dataLength = [data length];
NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:dataLength*2];
const unsigned char *dataBytes = [data bytes];
for (NSInteger idx = 0; idx < dataLength; ++idx) {
    [string appendFormat:@"%02x", dataBytes[idx]];
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In Swift you can create an extension.

```
extension NSData {

    func toHexString() -> String {

        var hexString: String = ""
        let dataBytes =  UnsafePointer<CUnsignedChar>(self.bytes)

        for (var i: Int=0; i<self.length; ++i) {
            hexString +=  String(format: "%02X", dataBytes[i])
        }

        return hexString
    }
}
```

Then you can simply use:

```
let keyData: NSData = NSData(bytes: [0x00, 0xFF], length: 2)

let hexString = keyData.toHexString()
println("\(hexString)") // Outputs 00FF
```

Answer (score 3):

Sadly there's no built-in way to produce hex from an NSData, but it's pretty easy to do yourself. The simple way is to just pass successive bytes into sprintf("%02x") and accumulate those into an NSMutableString. A faster way would be to build a lookup table that maps 4 bits into a hex character, and then pass successive nybbles into that table.

Comment: No need to use `sprintf`; NSMutableString has `appendFormat:`.

Answer (score 1):

While it may not be the most efficient way to do it, if you're doing this for debugging, SSCrypto has a category on NSData which contains two methods to do this (one for creating an NSString of the raw byte values, and one which shows a prettier representation of it).

http://www.septicus.com/SSCrypto/trunk/SSCrypto.m

Answer (score 1):

Seeing there is a Swift 1.2 snippet in the comments, here's the Swift 2 version since C style for loops are deprecated now. 
[Gist](https://gist.github.com/pheuberger/e1e3c12de4a0c83200cd) with MIT license and two simple unit tests if you care.

Here's the code for your convenience:

```
import Foundation

extension NSData {
  var hexString: String {
    let pointer = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(bytes)
    let array = getByteArray(pointer)

    return array.reduce("") { (result, byte) -> String in
      result.stringByAppendingString(String(format: "%02x", byte))
    }
  }

  private func getByteArray(pointer: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> [UInt8] {
    let buffer = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: pointer, count: length)

    return [UInt8](buffer)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already set:

```
NSData *myData = ...;
```

Simple solution:

```
NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",strData);
```