# obtaining NSData in hex format

Tags: cocoa, nsarray, nsdata

I have a function returning me NSData with hex inside:
eg:

```
NSData *temp = <000b4631 32202835 2047487a 2901088c 129824b0 48606c03 01a1070a >
```

Now these are hex values and I need to print them out.

```
x = 00
y = 0b 
z = 46 31
```

The ideal way to get them would be to convert them into a char array, as then I can map/typecast some structures to the array and read out what I want. How would I convert this NSData to a char array ?

Any other recommendations/best practices ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve NSData to Hex by length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805340/retrieve-nsdata-to-hex-by-length)

Comment: Your `NSData` object does not contain "hex inside", it just contains a hunk of bytes. Hex formatting is just a representation of those bytes.

Comment: Have you tried `NSData`'s `bytes` method?

Answer (score 2):

I have a category on NSData that does this https://github.com/Machx/Zangetsu/blob/master/Source/NSDataAdditions.m

```
-(NSString *)cw_hexString {
    NSUInteger capacity = [self length] * 2;
    NSMutableString *stringBuffer = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:capacity];
    const unsigned char *dataBuffer = [self bytes];

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [self length]; ++i) {
        [stringBuffer appendFormat:@"%02X ",(NSUInteger)dataBuffer[i]];
    }
    if (stringBuffer) {
        return stringBuffer;
    }
    return nil;
}
```