# How to convert Byte Array to NSString or to NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone

I am receiving some byte data from server as defined in following method

```
     - (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag
      {

      \//04 01 00
NSString *string = [
                    [NSString alloc] 
                    initWithData:data
                    encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                    ];
NSLog(string);

char *ptr = (void *)[data bytes]; // set a pointer to the beginning of your data bytes

if(*ptr == 0x06) {
    NSLog(@"okay,.. got a  0x06");
}
ptr++; // go to the next byte
if(*ptr == 0x05) {
    NSLog(@"okay,.. got a 0x05");
}
ptr++;
if(*ptr==0X00){
    NSLog(@"okay,.. got a 0X00");

}


//04 01 00
NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                         encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
///////////////////
///////////////////
NSLog(@"I received some thing , now trying to read it");
UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Data Received" message:newStr delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];

 [sock readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:0];
//NSLog(@"Reading %@",newStr);
```

}

I can compare the hexa values but not able to see in UIAlertView as I think I am not able to convert correctly , so please help how to convert in into NSString and in NSMutableArray so that I can use it dynamically

Comment: What do you expect the UIAlertView to display? The hex representation of the data?

Comment: yes , also i am not able to see data using NSLog, i have compared data by hard code , i want to compare as in array

Comment: If you want to see the hex representation of the raw binary data, you'll need to explicitly convert it, as in [How to convert an NSData into an NSString Hex string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520615/how-to-convert-an-nsdata-into-an-nsstring-hex-string)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try your code, but not all ascii characters can be represented visually. Try with some codes with ascii code >32, look for letters or numbers. Or echo the characters as decimal or hexa numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try  this,

```
   NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```