# How to Convert NSData to NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsdata

I know this has been asked quite before, and I already followed couple of approaches, but they don't work.

Following is what I already tried:

```
NSString *newStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseData bytes]];
NSString *newStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.*s", [responseData length], [responseData bytes]];
```

None of them works. In 1st case, it fills newStr with null. In 2nd, it fills with junk characters. I know from debugger log (po responseData) that I get valid response which is like bbbbbb 00 bbbbbb. [server sends them as byte array]

What to do?

EDIT:
I am receiving this data from http request response - using ASIHTTPRequest library, in case anybody can help on that line.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467844/convert-utf-8-encoded-nsdata-to-nsstring

Comment: I already tried the solution which is depicted there, mentioned above too.

Comment: Did you check whether your NSData is null or not?

Comment: Try the first line with simply `responseData` rather than `[responseData bytes]`

Comment: @c.cam108 - and which does not compile.

Comment: My mistake sorry, I forgot that `-stringWithUTF8String:` takes a `const char *`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert an NSData into an NSString Hex string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520615/how-to-convert-an-nsdata-into-an-nsstring-hex-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am posting this for records sake because I found a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12442672/1506363) and voting to close this down.

Actually what I am receiving is a stream of bytes represented as hex, and all the answers indicated do not work. Only [NSData description] gave me true data, which is something I can't use because it is intended for debugging.

Finally I tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12442672/1506363), and I get what I want. 
Thanks to all for trying to help out.

Answer (score 13):

Try this,

```
NSData *responseData; [Initialize it]
NSString *receivedDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
NSLog(@"%@",receivedDataString);
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try following code

```
NSString *string = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData: responseData.bytes encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code lines

```
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:data1.bytes length:data1.length encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: what are your data? I get this string from working project and its work well. May be you data encoding isn't UTF8?

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString  *image1Data = [[NSData dataWithData:myData] encodeBase64ForData];
```

But for this, you have to use NSData+Base64Additions class.

Answer (score 1):

Use following way

```
 NSString *dC_Str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decryPtd_data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] ;
```