# Convert a hash to NSString?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

Using the Evernote API, I have an object which has an NSUInteger property called `hash`. For the specific object I'm looking at, this is equal to:

```
<f5b5444b 33e740b7 f9d49a3b ddb6a39c>
```

I want to convert this into an NSString. Doing this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", noteResource.hash]
```

Gives me this:

```
530049088
```

How could I correctly convert the hash value to an NSString?

Comment: Eeeeuuuughhhh... Are you using a 128-bit machine? Or how can an `NSInteger` occupy 16 bytes?

Comment: Do you want this : http://stackoverflow.com/q/7520615/1603072 ?

Comment: @Vin It looks like it. The remaining problem is that it's an NSUInteger, what I have. How do I convert that to a `const void *`?

Comment: `noteResource` is an `NSData` object, and `noteResource.hash` is some hash value (NSUInteger). What do you mean by *"correctly convert the hash value to an NSString"*? Why convert to `const void *`? What result do you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see something output as "<" 8 hex digits space .... ">", it's the result of logging a NSData object (`NSLog(@"%@", myDataObject);`). So I believe what you have is not an `NSUInteger`, but a `NSData *` object.

There is no built in method to convert between strings and data, you need to do it in code:

```
- (NSString *)dataToString:(NSData *)data
{
    NSUInteger len = [data length];
    NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:len*2];
    const uint8_t *bptr = [data bytes];

    while(len--) [str appendFormat:@"%02.2x", *bptr++];

    return str;
}
```

If this works, you can write your own stringToData method reversing the above, if needed.