# NSString category using CommonCrypto returns nil in RubyMotion

Tags: ios, objective-c, rubymotion

I am trying to encrypt a string with HMAC-SHA1 using `CCHmac()`. I created an `NSString` category
for this:

**NSString+HMAC.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>

@interface NSString (HMAC)

- (NSString *)HMACSHA1WithKey:(NSString *)key;

@end
```

**NSString+HMAC.m**

```
#import "NSString+HMAC.h"

@implementation NSString (HMAC)

- (NSString *)HMACSHA1WithKey:(NSString *)key
{
    const char *cKey  = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    const char *cData = [self cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);

    NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:HMAC encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

@end
```

I am using this category from RubyMotion like so:

```
key = "ZjiUOHkl5tllz2PwaoZYrDRMkg9b43k5CcIOUjSE&"
string = "POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_consumer_key=XXX&oauth_nonce=OWhJeFpZbzRoVU4xck1RTENyN0w4T1J0czNIa01rSVA&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1389974660&oauth_version=1.0"
string.HMACSHA1WithKey(key) # => nil
```

However, the `HMACSHA1WithKey:` method returns `nil` all the time...

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the SHA-1 algorithm (which is stored in `HMAC`) is a sequence of
bytes, but not a valid UTF-8 sequence. Therefore

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithData:HMAC encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

fails and returns `nil`.

What you probably want is to convert the `NSData *HMAC` to a `NSString` containing the *hexadecimal representation* of the data.
There are many solutions available for that, for example [How to convert an NSData into an NSString Hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520615/how-to-convert-an-nsdata-into-an-nsstring-hex-string).

Comment: That was the problem indeed. What I did is convert the NSData to base64 (since I needed to do that anyway) from the category itself. And now it works!