# NSData displayed characters to NSString

Tags: php, objective-c, nsstring, nsdata, hmac

I am trying to copy some php to Objective-C and have stumbled upon a slight problem.

The php uses the line `substr(hash_hmac('sha256', $string, $token), 0, 20)` which outputs

```
ac56093452148b1f18e4
```

In Objective-C I use `CCHmac` like this:

```
NSData *hmacForKeyAndData(NSString *token, NSString *string)
{
    const char *cKey  = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    const char *cData = [data cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);
    return [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
}
```

which returns `NSData` which when logged is:

```
<ac560934 52148b1f 18e4385b cfa4f8cd cebe12c3 99d3281d 9f48c312 d6802449>
```

which looks the exact same as what php returns from `hash_hmac('sha256', $string, $token)`

I think you can see my problem here. I have the right output (It just needs trimming to 20 characters), but as `NSData`. If I convert the `NSData` to an `NSString` then I get a load of funny characters. I need to take the `NSData` `<ac560934>` and convert it into the string `ac560934`
Is this even possible? Or should I be using a different approach for the `hash_mac`?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520615/how-to-convert-an-nsdata-into-an-nsstring-hex-string

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I couldn't find that as there are so many NSData to NSString conversion questions.