# How do I convert apns data to string in Swift 3?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, nsdata, swift3

```
 let tokenChars = UnsafePointer<CChar>(deviceToken.bytes)
    var tokenString = ""

    for i in 0..<deviceToken.length {
        tokenString += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [tokenChars[i]])
    }

    DDLogDebug("Device Token: \(tokenString)")
```

^ This no longer works.  Mostly because there is no deviceToken.bytes anymore.

I tried to figure out how to use .withUnsafeBytes, but am failing.

Any help would be fantastic, I just need the string version of the device token, thanks!

Comment: Swift 3 solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520615/how-to-convert-an-nsdata-into-an-nsstring-hex-string/38131414#38131414.

Answer (score 2):

There is a one-line solution, `deviceToken` is `Data`

```
let tokenString = deviceToken.map{ String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
```

Comment: You are a god among men @vadian :D

When the time is up, I'll mark this as the best answer

Comment: There is nothing devine. I just read Swift Language Guide, Migration Guide and other documentation ;-)