# What kind of CFDataRef is printed out like "<b1a3c3 d4b5>"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

I tried using decimal and hexadecimal strings to create a `CFDataRef`, but what I created not what I need. I need a `CFDataRef` like "`<b1a3c3 d4b5>`", 
Here is my code:

```
CFDataRef abc = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, "b034958b0c6f",strlen("b034958b0c6f"));
CFDataRef abc = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, "4294967295", strlen("4294967295"));
```

Comment: You mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520615/how-to-convert-an-nsdata-into-an-nsstring-hex-string ? Then, there should be a bridge between CFDataRef & NSData

Comment: What are you asking? What is the problem?

Comment: The second argument to `CFDataCreate` is the raw bytes to store in the data. You can't pass a hexadecimal string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kevin is correct, you need to pass the raw bytes.

```
UInt8 bytes[] = { 0xb1, 0xa3, 0xc3, 0xd4, 0xb5 };
CFDataRef abc = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, bytes, sizeof(bytes));
```